# How to make conditional replacement of values in a column depending on values in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have data that looks like this:

```
currency    country
GBP         GB
USD         NaN
USD         US
AUD         AUD
GBP         NaN
```

Basically I'm trying to make conditional replacements of `NaN` in the country column to a value that's dependent on what the currency in that row is. (E.g. for `GBP` it should be `GB`).

I have a separate dict that maps currencies to country. But I'm not sure how to replace values in the country column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict`, also solution working if more columns in `DataFrame`:

```
#one possible solution is generate dictionary from existing values 
d = df.dropna().set_index('currency')['country'].to_dict()
#or use dictionary
#d = {'GBP': 'GB', 'USD': 'US', 'AUD': 'AUD'}
df['country'] = df['country'].fillna(df['currency'].map(d))
print (df)
  currency country
0      GBP      GB
1      USD      US
2      USD      US
3      AUD     AUD
4      GBP      GB
```

EDIT:

If all values of `currency` are in dictionary then solution should be simplify:

```
d = {'GBP': 'GB', 'USD': 'US', 'AUD': 'AUD'}
df['country'] = df['currency'].map(d)
print (df)
  currency country
0      GBP      GB
1      USD      US
2      USD      US
3      AUD     AUD
4      GBP      GB
```

If not, then if use only `map` it replace only matched values:

```
print (df)
  currency country
0     GBP1     GB1
1      USD     NaN
2      USD      US
3      AUD     AUD
4      GBP     NaN

d = {'GBP': 'GB', 'USD': 'US', 'AUD': 'AUD'}
df['country'] = df['currency'].map(d)
print (df)
  currency country
0     GBP1     NaN
1      USD      US
2      USD      US
3      AUD     AUD
4      GBP      GB
```

So if need original values which are not in dict (here GBP1) not replaced to `NaN`s use first solution:

```
d = {'GBP': 'GB', 'USD': 'US', 'AUD': 'AUD'}
df['country'] = df['country'].fillna(df['currency'].map(d))
print (df)
  currency country
0     GBP1     GB1
1      USD      US
2      USD      US
3      AUD     AUD
4      GBP      GB
```

Comment: very cool. Just curious though, could I just instead do `df['country'] = df['currency'].map(d)` and achieve the same result?

Comment: @doctopus - yes, if want map only. If need replace missing values add `fillna`

Comment: `.map()` returns a Series with all the filled in values though -- isn't it the same thing? (At least I get the same result, but just want to check if I may be missing something)

Comment: @doctopus - I think here is is same, but it depends of data. If all values of `currency` are in dictionary, then `map` return same values. If not, then there should be better use `fillna` + `map`. I try create another sample data for better explain.

Answer (score 2):

Assume you have dict `d`, you may use `set_index`, `fillna` and `reset_index`

```
d = {'GBP': 'GB', 'USD': 'US', 'AUD': 'AUD'}

df = df.set_index('currency').country.fillna(d).reset_index()

Out[39]:
  currency country
0      GBP      GB
1      USD      US
2      USD      US
3      AUD     AUD
4      GBP      GB
```